# working with linux dates column in R

Tags: linux, r, datetime, posixct

I have multiple pictures in a folder and each picture has a timestamp (in linux format) in it's name. I have provided an example of a timestamp on line3. My line 3 runs fine. But I get an error with 4th line. any hints?

my error is

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

filenames=list.files("//somepath/pictures")
timevalues=substr(filenames,8,17)
dates=as.POSIXct(1421679269, origin="1970-01-01")
dates2=as.POSIXct(timevalues, origin="1970-01-01")
dates
```

Comment: `dates2=as.POSIXct( as.numeric(timevalues), origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: thanks, it works. Please put it as an answer ...